# SharePoint PnP PowerShell Provision world clock webpart on Modern page

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, modern-experience, provisioning

I am working on modern team site page provisioning using pnp powershell. We are trying to add the world clock webpart on page, but we are not getting the internal name of the world clock webpart to add it on the page. Where can we get the internal name of the world clock or all the OOTB webpart internal name.?
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the web part as custom using the ID, for example:

```
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page $homePage -Component "b519c4f1-5cf7-4586-a678-2f1c62cc175a" -Section 1 -Column 1
```

You can find the ID by adding the part to the page and inspecting the element in dev tools. Search for data-sp-feature-instance-id.

Comment: Yes. This approach worked.